# Use `folder_exclude_patterns` to only ignore top-level directory

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a directory structure:

```
app
--controllers
----components
components
```

And in my sublime text 2 project file I want to ignore the top-level components directory (which was created by a `bower install` while keeping access to the `components` directory in `controllers`.

How do I do this?  Here's my current sublime settings:

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "path": "/path/to/Project",
      "folder_exclude_patterns": ["cake", "vendor", "node_modules", "components"],
      "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-workspace"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional paths to members of the `folder_exclude_patterns` array:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["cake", "vendor", "node_modules", "Project/components"],
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Right!  But I want to do the opposite: ignore the top-level components dir, and keep access to /app/controllers/components

Comment: @Civilian then just change `app` to the name of the folder containing your project - so if it's at `/path/to/Project`, make it `Project/components` and see if that works. I didn't realize `components` wasn't a subdir of `app`, it's a sister dir.

Answer (score 2):

as of 2020, (build 4067) [it's possible to reference project-folder](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/332#issuecomment-586245055-permalink) using '//'

`"folder_exclude_patterns": ["cake", "vendor", "node_modules", "//components"],`

before 2020, you could do:

`"folder_exclude_patterns": ["cake", "vendor", "node_modules", "/path/to/Project/components"],`

or on Windows - without ':'

`"folder_exclude_patterns": ["cake", "vendor", "node_modules", "C/path/to/Project/components"],`

Note there is no official release in 2020 yet, only dev.