# Exclude/Include folders differently with the same name in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to exclude a folder but only the one in the root directory.

```
//project-name.sublime-project

{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/project",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["?"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I found [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12850) on the Sublime forum where they talk about `root_dir`. But it's not exactly `root_dir`, its just a pattern that happen to work for them. It could be `any_name_dir`. Unfortunately for me I have the exact same name-pattern further down the tree.

My structure:

```
app_name
├── src
│   ├── app_name
│   │   ├── static
│   │   └── templates
│   ├── other1
│   └── other2
└── static    <----
```

Is it possible to ONLY exclude the `static` folder thats in the root, aka `app_name` eg.

```
"folder_exclude_patterns: ["./static"]"
```

Comment: Please do not use URL shorteners.

Comment: Can you please describe your directory structure in a little more detail and indicate which folder(s) you'd like to exclude, and which you want to include?

Comment: duplicate - there is also answer with new feature (2020) for this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746923/use-folder-exclude-patterns-to-only-ignore-top-level-directory/64377704#64377704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in way to exclude folders / files specifically.

`folder_exclude_patterns` and `file_exclude_patterns` inputs are treated as wildcards.

---

However, you can use `folder_include_patterns` as follows:

*(It can get absurd if you have too many folders)*

```
{
  "path": ".",
  "folder_include_patterns": ["src"],
}
```

This will include only `src` directory with its subdirectories and ignore other folders.

Comment: It didn't answer the root-question but it solved my problem, thanks!